# how can I open an image of FileStorage type in Pillow

Tags: python, image, flask, request, python-imaging-library

in my flask app after receiving POST request and running the code

```
image = request.files['image']
```

image variable have type
<FileStorage: 'image.png' ('image/png')>

how can i convert it to Pillow image or open with Image.open() ?

Comment: `FileStorage` is not image type but only wrapper on normal file like `PNG/JPG/PDF/Excel/etc.` which flask keeps in some temporary place. It keeps all information about this file. You can use `image.save(...)` to save file in own destination. You can use `image.read()` to read it as bytes data. And then you can use it with `io.BytesIO` to create file in memeory which can be read by `Pillow` like any normal file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileStorage` is not image type but only wrapper on normal files like `PNG/JPG/PDF/Excel/etc.` which flask uses to keep information about original files and which gives you direct access to original file - probably as `file handler` - and Pillow can use it directly to read image (without saving to file, and without using `io.Bytes` to create file image in memory)

```
    image = request.files['image']
    img = Image.open(image)  # load with Pillow

    print(img.size)          # show image size (width, height)
    img = img.convert('L')   # convert to greyscale 
    img.save('output.png')   # save it 

    #draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img) # create object to draw figures or text on image
```

All modules/functions which can use `file handler` instead of `filename` (to read file) should read from `FileStorage` without problem.

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code - tested with images .png, .jpg, .webp

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print(request.files)
    if request.files:
        image = request.files['image']
        
        # pillow
        img = Image.open(image)
        print(img.size) 
        img = img.convert('L')  # greyscale
        img.save('output.png')
        
    return render_template_string('''<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: i tried that already and im getting error PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <FileStorage: 'image.png' ('image/png')>

Comment: did you check if you can read this image directly with Pillow ? Maybe problem is not code but file. Did you do something more with `FileStorage` - ie. did you do `image.read()` ? It may moves file pointer to the end of file so next function may try to read from the end of file - and then It may need `image.seek(0)` to move pointer to the beginning of file.

Comment: I added minimal working code which works for me.

Comment: Okey you are right. the problem was this file. Now everything works. Thanks

Comment: I also tested code with empty file and it gives me error `PIL.UnidentifiedImageError`

Answer (score -1):

@furas thank you! Your tip on `image.seek(0)` worked for me, this was the cause of my issue. My pointer was at the end of file when I was trying to access it after verifying.

Comment: This answer should be a comment on furas's answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30442494)